# Bug Function Pointer in IAR

Tags: c, embedded

I'm working with IAR and I'm getting the following Error:

```
Error[Pe513]: a value of type "void *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "void (*)(void)"
```

Below is the code that generates the error :

```
uint32_t resethandler_adress = (volatile uint32_t)(FLASH_SECTOR2_BASE_ADRESSE + 4);

void (*app_reset_handler)(void);
app_reset_handler = (void*)resethandler_adress;
```

Comment: What is resethandler_adress and why are you casting it to void?

Comment: Sorry i missing to share with you code where im getting this adress:

Comment: uint32_t resethandler_adress = *(volatile uint32_t*)(FLASH_SECTOR2_BASE_ADRESSE + 4);

Comment: So what is the question here? Clearly, the compiler does not like the idea of assigning a void pointer value into a variable that is of type pointer to function accepting no arguments and returning nothing. I don't like that idea either. What were you expecting? There are several ways this could be written to make the compiler quiet, but it is hard to tell which is the correct way without knowing what you are trying to do.

Comment: The aim is to hold the reset handler adresse of the Application via pointer to function .

Comment: You should probably be using a linker script to define this symbol.

Comment: Why do you need a function pointer to begin with?

Answer (score 1):

As the error states, a `void (*)(void)` is not the same as a `void*`.  The solution is to cast the integer to the appropriate type.  This can be done directly; it is not clear why you cast it to `uint32_t` then to `void*` - or why you might declare a literal constant `volatile`.

```
typedef void (*tResetHandlerFn)(void);
tResetHandlerFn app_reset_handler = (tResetHandlerFn)(FLASH_SECTOR2_BASE_ADDRESS + 4) ;
```

Comment: What was not clear in the question to me was whether (FLASH_SECTOR2_BASE_ADDRESS + 4) was the start of the handler function or the address where a pointer to the handler function is stored. It looks suspiciously like an ARM 7 vector table (especially the + 4), in which case it would be the later and another level of indirection would be required.

Comment: @andymango : Indeed, but while we may suspect that this code may not be semantically correct; the question is specifically about the syntactic correctness.  Once it compiles, he will be able to test and debug other issues - or post a new question.

Comment: @Clifford : Actually, I learne How to build bootloader on stm32F4xx, The guy how give the course have used Keil to Build his project,  but in my project i use IAR, so there is some difference when compiling the project cross this 2 platefrom. He use , in order to get the adresse of reset handler a pointer to function .

Comment: @zinhom69 and so have I. What is your point? However Andy's point is probably calibration in this case; the value _at_ that address is the function address, not the address itself. There is no difference between IAR and Keil in this. However your question was about neither of those issues. When it does not work, post a new question.

Comment: @zinhom69 you need to cast the address to a uint32_t*, then dereference that to get the integer address of the entry point, then cast _that_ to the function pointer.

Answer (score 0):

In this: `uint32_t resethandler_adress = (volatile uint32_t)(FLASH_SECTOR2_BASE_ADRESSE + 4);`

You need to get the hex value stored at address `(volatile uint32_t)(FLASH_SECTOR2_BASE_ADRESSE + 4)`

Try with this

```
*(volatile uint32_t *)(FLASH_SECTOR2_BASE_ADRESSE + 4)
```